# What's this type of chart called?

Tags: terminology, visualization

What's the name of this type of chart?

[image: WTF Chart]

Comment: Um, a spider-web chart?

Comment: I know this is a year and a half old, but I came in to ask this exact same question. Don't know how I just happened to come across this. Glad I did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's more commonly known as [Radar Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart).